# JButton action is not performed inside of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I got a simple JTable which one of it's cells is an `Edit` button which needs to open a new `JDialog`.

After a several examples from the web I created a new class which implements `TableCellRenderer` and returned a JButton from it but the button is not doing what I need for some reason.

This is my code:

```
final MessageResourcesTableModel model = new MessageResourcesTableModel(columnNames);

JTable resultsTable = new JTable(model);
resultsTable.setShowGrid(true);
resultsTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
resultsTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(resultsTable.getPreferredSize());
resultsTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
resultsTable.setFont(font13);

final TableCellRenderer buttonRenderer = new JTableButtonRenderer();
resultsTable.getColumn(COLUMN_EDIT).setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);
```

And this is the renderer:

```
class JTableButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(final JTable table, final Object value, final boolean isSelected, final boolean hasFocus, final int row, final int column) {
        final JButton editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        editButton.setOpaque(true);

        editButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Hi from Action !!!");

            }
        });
        return editButton;
    }
}
```

Although there is a simple ActionListener implementation, there is nothing over the console

Comment: [How to use tables: Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Answer (score 1):

A renderer only displays the data in the cell. You can't add an ActionListener to the button because it is not a real component. A renderer only paints an image of the button in the table.

You need to create a custom editor if you want to be able to click on the button.

See [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for an editor implementation that does this for you.

Comment: @roeygol post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem.